# NPM module "sound-play" breaked

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

After update NodeJS from 12.13 to 12.14 "sound-play" module doesn't work anymore. Before update everything worked OK. Any ideas, please?

P.S. Win10 x64 LTSC 1809 17763, gulp 4, PATH is OK...

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_tp\wp-content\themes>gulp sound
[17:40:33] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_tp\wp-content\themes\gulpfile.js
[17:40:33] Starting 'sound'...
[17:40:33] Finished 'sound' after 10 ms
(node:3888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: powershell -c Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore; $player = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer; $player.open('C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_tp\wp-content\themes\notification.mp3'); $player.Play(); Start-Sleep 1; Start-Sleep -s $player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;Exit;
"powershell" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:498:23)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
(node:3888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3888) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: The issue here will be that there will be built / compiled dependancies that have become incompatible. It shouldn't really happen going from 12.13 to 12.14, but you need to wipe out all the downloaded node_modules. You can't do a refresh, because the already downloaded dependancy packages will already be at the right level, and you need to force a recompile / rebuild of any dependancies.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't helped. I've cleaned all the folders containing node modules, deleted nodejs, reinstall everything from the scratch but result is the same.

Comment: Because you have a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` if looks like some code somewhere is missing a now required `.catch((err)=>{})` block. Is any of this your code or code that you can edit? If so look for `.then(...` clauses after a returned promise and add the `.catch(...` block.